# Hibernate FetchType.LAZY doesnt load on demand and no SQL query logging

Tags: java, jpa

I am expecting when running the line code below on the Test file, an extra SQL query running on demand like 'select from StockDailyRecordEntity where stockid = ?' but nothing been shown up

see the fetching childs using ----lazy or eager way---- logging below

```
Hibernate: insert into trx_stock_daily_record (stock_desc, stock) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into trx_stock_daily_record (stock_desc, stock) values (?, ?)
2021-09-13 21:37:08.639 TRACE 37616 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
2021-09-13 21:37:08.639  INFO 37616 --- [           main] r.StockRepoPerformance                   : <------  Starting new Search ------>
2021-09-13 21:37:08.641 TRACE 37616 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Don't need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByStockId]: This method isn't transactional.
Hibernate: select stockentit0_.stock_id as stock_id1_6_, stockentit0_.stock_code as stock_co2_6_, stockentit0_.stock_name as stock_na3_6_ from trx_stock stockentit0_ where stockentit0_.stock_id=?
2021-09-13 21:37:08.680  INFO 37616 --- [           main] r.StockRepoPerformance                   : fetching childs using get method
2021-09-13 21:37:08.680  INFO 37616 --- [           main] r.StockRepoPerformance                   : child entity size -->10
2021-09-13 21:37:08.680  INFO 37616 --- [           main] r.StockRepoPerformance                   : fetching childs using ----lazy or eager way----
2021-09-13 21:37:08.680  INFO 37616 --- [           main] r.StockRepoPerformance                   : child desc-->Mon Sep 13 21:37:08 MYT 2021
2021-09-13 21:37:08.685  INFO 37616 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext             : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@7c98bac0 testClass = StockRepoPerformance, testInstance = repo.StockRepoPerformance@bc85538, testMethod = testPerformanceInsert@StockRepoPerformance, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6fc9c0cc testClass = StockRepoPerformance, locations = '{}', classes = '{class repo.CovidRepoTest}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1a75e76a, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@57a78e3, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2767e23c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@59402b8f], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true]]
2021-09-13 21:37:08.689  INFO 37616 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-09-13 21:37:08.690  INFO 37616 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-13 21:37:08.694  INFO 37616 --- [       Thread-4] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-09-13 21:37:08.696  INFO 37616 --- [       Thread-4] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Refer to this [Baedung guide](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading)

```
select orderdetai0_.USER_ID as USER_ID4_0_0_, orderdetai0_.ORDER_ID as ORDER_ID1_1_0_, orderdetai0_ ...
  from USER_ORDER orderdetai0_ where orderdetai0_.USER_ID=?
```

Based on the logging. It doesn't not make any difference when fetching by lazy or eager for the line of code below.

StockDailyRecordEntity child = childs.get(0);

```
package repo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.app.advance.entity.StockDailyRecordEntity;
import com.app.advance.entity.StockEntity;
import com.app.advance.repo.StockDailyRecordRepo;
import com.app.advance.repo.StockRepo;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest

public class StockRepoPerformance {

    @Autowired
    StockRepo stockRepo;

    @Autowired
    StockDailyRecordRepo stockDailyReportRepo;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testPerformanceInsert() {
        StockEntity stockEntity = new StockEntity();
        stockEntity.setStockCode("Code");
        stockEntity.setStockName(new Date().toString());
        // stockRepo.save(stockEntity);
        List<StockDailyRecordEntity> stockDailyRecords = new ArrayList<StockDailyRecordEntity>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            StockDailyRecordEntity stockDailyRecordEntity = new StockDailyRecordEntity();
            stockDailyRecordEntity.setStock(stockEntity);
            stockDailyRecordEntity.setDesc(new Date().toString());

            stockDailyRecords.add(stockDailyRecordEntity);
            // stockDailyReportRepo.save(stockDailyRecordEntity);

        }

        stockEntity.setStockDailyRecords(stockDailyRecords);
        // stockEntity.setStockDailyRecordsEager(stockDailyRecords);
        stockRepo.save(stockEntity);

        log.info("<------  Starting new Search ------>");
        List<StockEntity> list = stockRepo.findByStockId(stockEntity.getStockId());
        stockEntity = list.get(0);

        log.info("fetching childs using get method");
        // Set<StockDailyRecordEntity> childs = stockEntity.getStockDailyRecordsEager();
        List<StockDailyRecordEntity> childs = stockEntity.getStockDailyRecords();

        log.info("child entity size -->" + childs.size());
        log.info("fetching childs using ----lazy or eager way----");
        StockDailyRecordEntity child = childs.get(0);
        log.info("child desc-->" + child.getDesc());

    }
}

    
    package com.app.advance.entity;
    
    import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;
    
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;
    
    // https://mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "trx_stock")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class StockEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4174876690328458921L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer stockId;
    
        @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", nullable = false, length = 10)
        private String stockCode;
    
        @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", nullable = false, length = 200)
        private String stockName;
        
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock", orphanRemoval = true)
        @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private List<StockDailyRecordEntity> stockDailyRecords = new ArrayList<StockDailyRecordEntity>();
        
        //@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "stock", orphanRemoval = true)
        //@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
        //@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        //private List<StockDailyRecordEntity> stockDailyRecordsEager = new ArrayList<StockDailyRecordEntity>();
    }
    
    package com.app.advance.entity;
    
    import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
    
    import java.util.Set;
    
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "trx_stock_daily_record")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class StockDailyRecordEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7102491956593238645L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "RECORD_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer recordId;
    
        //@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false)
        private StockEntity stock;
        
        @Column(name = "STOCK_DESC", length = 200)
        private String desc;
    
    }
    
    #spring.main.banner-mode=off
    lombok.log.fieldName = logger
    server.port=8081
    
    spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
    
    ## PostgreSQL
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xx:5432/xxx
    spring.datasource.username=admin
    spring.datasource.password=password
    
    
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
    # spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: In your insertSingleRecord method, i can not find `stockEntity.setStockDailyRecords(stockDailyRecords);` Please set  stockDailyRecords in stockEntity and run the test again

Comment: @Nitika modified

Comment: uncomment @ManyToOne annotation line from StockDailyRecordEntity

Comment: @Nitika by removing that .. table wont auto created.. error during startup

Comment: as per insert command printed in logs, i cannot see one more column (STOCK_ID). Can you please share what is your schema ?

Comment: @Nitika updated schema. The program works under restful controller file but not JUnit test file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237075/discussion-between-nitika-and-little-star).